# How to treat special character when casting string kdb

Tags: special-characters, kdb

When casting a value to a string (via "string" keyword)

```
 Ex.
 t:([]stuff:`a`b`c)
 select string stuff from t
```

Adds a weird special character before final `0a` when calling from k function (via C client)

```
 0x0180
```

What is this ? What is best way of handling it ? Is there anyway to get a string without this special character ?

```
 stuff,more
 a,1.2�
 b,2.3�
 c,3.4�
```

Comment: When i view special char in vim it looks like this `^A<80>`

Comment: Can you post the entire bytecode stream that you're seeing? That might help

Comment: What is "Bytecode stream" ? You mean hex dump from xxd?

Comment: Sorry I mean the full result that you get back from the k function via C client. You said it "adds a weird special character before final 0a" but I was curious to see all of the result. I presume it's small enough to paste here

Comment: sure, pasted it, all i do is printf "%s"  the column from result array and last column adds this special character, regardless what type of value is there

Comment: If you can’t find help here you could try community.kx.com.

Answer (score 0):

The special character does not appear in a q session

```
q)select string stuff from t
stuff
-----
,"a"
,"b"
,"c"
```

so one supposes your problem arises from the [C API](https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/capiref/). Not being familiar with the API, the rest of this is speculative. Sorry.

If you are working through the API, perhaps you do not need a table returned, only the column values. Is [`exec`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/exec/) perhaps closer to what you want?

```
q)exec string stuff from t
,"a"
,"b"
,"c"
```

If so, do you still see the character you ask about?

Comment: exec serves a completely different purpose , im not sure what will happen when i printf the result , but it's not really what i want